# Approximate a 3d mean curvature skeleton with a 3d articulated skeleton (line segments)

Tags: opencv, graphics, computer-vision, point-cloud-library, cgal

In the 2d case `cv::approxPolyDP`([link](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp)) can approximate a set of 2d points forming a contour with a polygonal curve, i.e. a set of lines. An example found online is depicted in the following image, where the contour on the left is approximated with the polygonal curve on the right. This is very useful for some case, e.g. to compute less noisy contour normals. 
[image]

I'm looking for something similar in the 3d case. More precisely, the [version 4.7](http://www.cgal.org/2015/10/20/cgal-47/) of [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) comes with a new component that computes the [mean curvature skeleton](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_skeletonization/index.html) of a 3d mesh. The skeleton output has the form of an un-ordered series of 3d skeleton points (and the corresponding skeleton edges). An example for a horse mesh is taken from their website:

[image]

I would like to have an approximation of this skeleton with an articulated skeleton, i.e. an ensemble of straight 3d line segments (not infinite lines like [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=fitline#fitline) or [here](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_sample_consensus_model_line.html#details)), that looks more similar to the following example:

[image]

Fitting a shape primitive e.g. cylinder to the mesh or pointcloud (e.g. methods in [PCL](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__sample__consensus.html) or [CGAL](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_shape_detection_3/index.html)) is not a choice because it imposes a prior on the data.

A pointer in that direction could be useful, especially if there are tools readily available. There is already a different working solution, but the above described way could be more elegant, as in the 2d case.

Answer (score 1):

A good example of something very similar would be Pinocchio: 
http://www.mit.edu/~ibaran/autorig/index.html.

On the site there is a paper which explains the algorithm; roughly speaking, it first flood-fills the model with spheres, and computes the optimal modified version of a generic human skeleton such that the skinning weights are evenly distributed. *However* to do so for *any* general model would be much more difficult - you would have to compute the optimal number of bones as well.